# Is it possible to paginate term aggregation result with search term?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Is it possible to use pagination in term aggregation query with a search term?

I need to paginate the result of the following query I am not able to find any solution ?

```
{
    "sort": [{
        "create_date": {
            "order": "desc"
        }
    }],
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": []
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "genres": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "mentions.keyword",
                "include": "insta.*"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `size` and `from` to tell the engine to return the documents in that range every time you come back for next page. Have two variables in your service design and whoever calls the service should also pass the two variables values (basically documents from and the limit)

```
   {
     "from": from,
     "size": limit,
     "sort": [{
         "create_date": {
             "order": "desc"
          }
     }],
   "query": {
     "bool": {
        "must": []
    }
},
"aggs": {
    "genres": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "mentions.keyword",
            "include": "insta.*"
        }
    }
   }
 }
```

if you exposed this query through a service for example `mysearch` then call the service like this

```
 mysearch?searchTerm=theWord&from=0&limit=15
```

and in the next call you do the same but with different `from` and `limit` values

```
  mysearch?searchTerm=theWord&from=16&limit=15
```

if this information is not enough then post some sample documents to play with

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to fetch documents inside terms aggregation, you can use either of two options

1. In terms aggregation you can use partition to paginate data.
   Refer document [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_with_partitions)
2. You can use [composite](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html) aggregation .
   In composite aggregtion you can only access data sequentially using after key. You won't be able to jump pages.

Comment: With partition to paginate can I pass a search term ?

`"include": {
               "partition": 0,
               "num_partitions": 20
            },`

Comment: You can use aggregations to filter terms aggregation buckets https://medium.com/hepsiburadatech/how-to-create-faceted-filtered-search-with-elasticsearch-75e2fc9a1ae3.  Number of partitions you need to calculate based on size and total records